# POST data encoding for request to Hackerrank API

Tags: php, http, post

Hackerrank API documentation explains how send POST request to it.

However, 'source' and 'testcases' parameters supposedly should be encoded, though I could not understand how exactly. I tried urencode (in PHP) on each of them and then building string with `=` and `&` characters, but I get "400 bad request".

**UPD** Sorry for forgotten link to documentation page:
http://www.hackerrank.com/api/docs
third tab here shows sample with using curl.

Comment: Show your code and link to the relevant part of the Hackerrank documentation.

Comment: Thanks for reminding about url to documentation. As about code, since I thought the problem is in encoding url, I did not think the snippet would help.

However I found the problem was inside my library method for POSTing. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, it was the bug inside my library for sending POST requests. No problems with my code or hackerrank (Which works like charm).

Here is the sample of my query building, in `PHP`:

```
$input = '10 8';
$code = 'print 14';
$url = 'http://api.hackerrank.com/checker/submission.json';
$key = 'somekey|asdfasd|keydata';

$query = array();

$query['source'] = urlencode($code);
$query['testcases'] = urlencode(json_encode(array($input)));
$query['lang'] = 5;
$query['api_key'] = urlencode($key);

$q = array();
foreach ($query as $k => $v) {
    $q[] = "$k=$v";
}
$q = implode("&", $q);
```

Now `$q` could be used as data for POST request (for me with http_get_contents it is ok).